# Setting Adapter to ExpendableListView type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, expandablelistview, listadapter

When i try to set the adapter to my ExpendableListView it expects ListAdapter but i want to use a custom ExpandableListAdapter which extends BaseExpandableListAdapter

This is my ExpandableListView:

```xml
<ExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:id="@+id/exp_lv_nav">
</ExpandableListView>
```

Setting the adapter:

```kotlin
exp_lv_nav.adapter = ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild, exp_lv_nav)
```

And this is what I get when building:

```
Error : Type mismatch: inferred type is ExpandableListAdapter but ListAdapter! was expected
```

Top of my adapter:

```java
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ExpandedMenuModel> mListDataHeader; 

    private HashMap<ExpandedMenuModel, List<String>> mListDataChild;
    ExpandableListView expandList;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<ExpandedMenuModel> listDataHeader, HashMap<ExpandedMenuModel, List<String>> listChildData, ExpandableListView mView) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mListDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.mListDataChild = listChildData;
        this.expandList = mView;
    }
```

Comment: `exp_lv_nav.adapter = ExpandableListAdapter(this, 
           listDataHeader, listDataChild, exp_lv_nav)` hmmm it doesn't looks like `java` ... and if's it's Kotlin ... then ... well ....  `setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter)`  and  `setAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter adapter)` fu*** up Kotlin binding

Comment: Its Kotlin indeed

Comment: ... so did you tried to use setter directly?

Comment: The kotlin way to set the adapter dont work with custom adapters. just WTF

Answer (score 9):

It seems to be a problem in Kotlin. For now, instead of setting the adapter using Kotlin's generated getter/setter as you have in the question:

```
exp_lv_nav.adapter = ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild, exp_lv_nav)
```

replace with:

```
exp_lv_nav.setAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild, exp_lv_nav))
```