# Error trying to set adapter, suggests to also implement android.widget.listview

Tags: android, kotlin, listview

I'm having the following error when trying to set the adapter to the ListView:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is SeriesListAdapter but ListAdapter! was expected
```

It suggest to make the adapter extends android.widgets.listview, but extending this interface make it needs to implements a lot of functions that as can be seen by the commented overrides, I've tried to implement but it keep crashing the app on launch with an "Could not inflate error".

Can someone help by either showing how to proper set the adapter, because by what I've seen in tutorials and such, it should not have this type mismatch

this is my adapter:

```kotlin
class SeriesListAdapter (
    private val context: Context,
    private val seriesRepository: SeriesCardRepository,
    private val listView: ListView
        ) :
    ListAdapter<Series, SeriesListAdapter.SeriesViewHolder>(SeriesListAdapter) {

    /**
     * @Description Class responsible for calculating the difference between two lists, and returning us
     * a updated list for exhibition, the ItemCallback will calculate the difference between two
     * items in the list using, so we implement how this will happen
     */
    private companion object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Series>() {

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Series, newItem: Series): Boolean {
            return oldItem.name == newItem.name
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Series, newItem: Series): Boolean {
            return oldItem.name == newItem.name && oldItem.lastChapter == newItem.lastChapter
                    && oldItem.image == newItem.image && oldItem.lastUpdate == newItem.lastUpdate
        }

        private var TAG = "SeriesListAdapter"
    }

    override fun getItem(index: Int): Series {
        return seriesRepository.getSerieByIndex(index)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SeriesViewHolder {
        return SeriesViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SeriesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
//        holder.bind(getItem(position), click)
    }

    class SeriesViewHolder(
        private var view: View
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        private val seriesImage: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.series_image_id)
        private val seriesName: MaterialTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.series_name_text_field)
        private var lastChapter: MaterialTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.latest_chapter_text)
        private val uploadedIn: MaterialTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.last_uploaded_in_text)
//        private val positiveButton: MaterialButton = view.findViewById(R.id.positive)
        // TODO: Learn what the heck was this button XD

        fun bind(data: Series, click: (Series) -> Unit) {
            with(view) {
//                positiveButton.setOnClickListener { click.invoke(data) }
                seriesName.text = data.name
                lastChapter.text = data.lastChapter
                uploadedIn.text = data.lastUpdate
                seriesImage.setImageResource(data.image)
            }
        }

        fun bind(data: Series) {
            with(view) {
//                positiveButton.setOnClickListener { click.invoke(data) }
                seriesName.text = data.name
                lastChapter.text = data.lastChapter
                uploadedIn.text = data.lastUpdate
                seriesImage.setImageResource(data.image)
            }
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup?): SeriesViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
                val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.base_card, parent, false)

                return SeriesViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }


//    override fun getCount(): Int {
//        return seriesRepository.size
//    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return getItem(position).name.hashCode().toLong()
    }

//    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
//        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.base_card, parent, false)
//        val seriesNameTextView: MaterialTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.series_name_id)
//        val seriesUpdateTextView: MaterialTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.last_uploaded_in_id)
//        val seriesChapterTextView: MaterialTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.latest_chapter_id)
//        val seriesImageView:ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.series_image_id)
//        val series = getItem(position)
//
//        seriesNameTextView.text = series.name
//        seriesUpdateTextView.text = series.lastChapter
//        seriesChapterTextView.text = series.lastChapter
//        seriesImageView.setImageResource(series.image)
//
//        return view
//    }
//
//    override fun getViewTypeCount(): Int {
//        return seriesRepository.size
//    }
//
//    override fun isEmpty(): Boolean {
//        return seriesRepository.size == 0
//    }
//
//    override fun areAllItemsEnabled(): Boolean {
//        return isEmpty
//    }
//
//    override fun isEnabled(position: Int): Boolean {
//        return true
//    }
}
```

and this is how I'm trying to set in the activity:

```kotlin
// declared as private lateinit var cardListView: ListView
cardListView = findViewById(R.id.card_list_view)
cardListView.adapter = SeriesListAdapter(this,
SeriesCardRepository().also { it.populateWithProps(10) }, cardListView
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57710170/setting-adapter-to-expendablelistview-type-mismatch) - try using `list.setAdapter(stuff)` instead of `list.adapter = stuff`

Comment: Remove this     private val listView: ListView
 and replace this with   private val dataSeries: List<Series> and use this dataSeries value for your multiple functions.

Comment: It does not work even using `listView.setAdapter(adapter)` instead, it gives the same error.

Comment: If I use `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`, I can set the adapter with no problem, but this is not what I wanted.